# Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications, clearSCADA, SCADA

Tags: vba, excel, scada

Developing an interface in excel to access a database in a SCADA application (clearSCADA by Schneider)

Require the ability to list all properties of an object in Visual Basic behind excel.

It is very simple to list all the object based on a property like "InService". And to create an array of all objects.

```
Set oPnts = myFolder.List("CDBObject")

For Each item In oPnts

            Set oObj = oServ.FindObject(oPnts.item(Count + 1).FullName)
Next Item
```

But I am not able to list all the properties of an object. Like CNDP3AnalogIn.

I want to do something like this. oObj.list and get an array of all the properties associated with object.

How I am solving this problem currently is hard coding all the properties associated with an object and using 'case select' statements and printing them to excel. This method is not dynamic and does not solve the issue of new properties added with .xml files.

I think the issue might have to do with the ability to use methods such as 'list' on an object to find properties.

Willing to write some C to approach this issue from another perspective. Just a push in the right direction would be great!!

Build details:

Excel 2016
Microsoft Visual Basic For Application 7.1
VBA: Retail 7.1.1056

Comment: open up the VB ide from the developer toolbar, go to the Tools menu, and choose References. Create a reference to the dll that contains the objects you are interested. Then press F2 to show the object browser. In the dropdown that says "All libraries" choose just the dll you selected. Then you can visually browse all of the objects and properties that the object has. You'll still have to know what properties you want to access, and hard code those.

Comment: You may use backup scada for example ScadaLTS that have access all data in database or json and You may generate report or (inteface) to excel use pentaho software.